# Adding a column to a select statement based on the existence of a record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a SQL query that I would like to add a column to the recordset which has a value based on the existence of a record in another table.  I have a left join joining the tables, and I am assuming I have to do some sort of pivot in my SQL, but I am not familiar with table pivoting.

My existing SQL is

```
SELECT tabs.name,tabs.id AS tabid,tabs.sort,fields.id AS fieldid, fields.label
FROM tabs
INNER JOIN fields
  ON tabs.id = fields.tabid
LEFT JOIN fields_reports
  ON fields_reports.fieldid = fields.id
WHERE fields_reports.reportid = 57
GROUP BY fields.id
ORDER BY tabs.sort, fields.id
```

What happened in the SQL is that it pulls field (which is the core of the statement) and the tabs (which are essentailly categories).  The fields_reports table maps fields to reports that I am building.

What I need to do is add a column to my statement that says: if the current field has a record in the fields_reports table with the report number passed in (57) then assign the column value of 1, else 0.

**Edit:**  I have another issue with the query.  Right now the query is only pulling fields attached to one report.  Instead of using a case is there a way that I can do a subquery to select from the fields_reports table so that I can pull all fields and then have the column attaching it to a report?

This is the query that pulls the records now, but only pulls one reports fields

```
SELECT tabs.name,tabs.id AS tabid,tabs.sort,fields.id AS fieldid, fields.label,
  CASE WHEN fields_reports.id IS null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS inReport
FROM fields
INNER JOIN tabs
  ON tabs.id = fields.tabid
LEFT JOIN fields_reports
  ON fields_reports.fieldid = fields.id
WHERE fields_reports.reportid = 57
GROUP BY fields.id
ORDER BY tabs.sort, fields.id
```

Let me know if I should open up a new question for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
You can `SELECT ..., IF(field_reports.reportid=57),1,0), ... FROM ...`
```

**EDIT** The test on reportid in the WHERE clause will need to be removed, or else this makes little sense as a solution. (Thanks to @Dave Long for this.)

Comment: Sorry for confusing your name, I didn't mean that. :) Actually there seems to be one other issue with your answer. The `GROUP BY` list does not include `fields_reports.reportid`, and this field is not aggregated in your solution. The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) states for such cases: `The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same.` Obviously all values of `fields_reports.reportid` are not necessarily the same for any particular `fields.id` that we are grouping by.

Answer (score 1):

Look what I've done to your script:

```
SELECT tabs.name,tabs.id AS tabid,tabs.sort,fields.id AS fieldid, fields.label
FROM tabs
INNER JOIN fields
  ON tabs.id = fields.tabid
LEFT JOIN fields_reports
  ON fields.id = fields.id AND fields_reports.reportid = 57
GROUP BY fields.id
ORDER BY tabs.sort, fields.id
```

Noticed something different? I dropped the `WHERE` clause and moved the condition to the `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN fields_reports`. `WHERE`, as it was specified, turned your LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN, so the result set would only try to select the rows with `fields_reports.reportid = 57`. If there were no such rows, none would be returned, i.e. that way you couldn't have your flag column working.

But now it can be defined, for example, like this:

```
MAX(CASE fields_reports.reportid WHEN 57 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TheFlagColumn
```

Just append it to your select list.

Comment: Although this would work I have awarded Todd Hopp with the answer as his was correct in less code.

Comment: @Dave Long: You know better, but otherwise I must say that though Todd's answer is basically fine, it cannot be applied to your query as it is. I mean, your query can only select `reportid = 57`, so the flag column, as defined by Todd, is pointless. In my answer I've already addressed the issue you have just raised in the update to the original question.

Comment: I thought that it was obvious that the WHERE clause test on reportid would have to be removed. Otherwise, as you correctly point out, the "solution" would make no sense.

Comment: You are correct in saying that.  In Ted's post you do need to remove the where clause.
@Ted - You may want to add that to your answer as people who find this post on the web may not find that obvious.  I didn't at first.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase would be:

```
select ....
     , case when LeftJoinedTable.column is null then 0 else 1 end
  from ....
```

this works because, when you left join and no row exists in the joined table, the columns are still present in the result but they are all null.  So you can test for this null value to see if you matched to a row in the right side of the join.